# Getting data from Dynamic added tables with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

Please assume that we are creating a project for a corporation with 10 employees and each employee has a table in our database. we can simply work with this tables using entity. But in future the number of employees will be added and our application must dynamically create table for them. How to work with these new tables using entity?

Comment: I hope this is about multi tenancy, not about very bad database design. Can you give some more background?

Comment: Hi Gert Arnold and sorry for my bad English. In that corporation the administrator wants to manage a few dental clinic for setting appointments in blank times. If we put all appointments data in one table this will be huge. So I decided to separate table of clinics and put data (Appointments) in these tables separately. Now the number of clinics is 4 and I can add them to my entity. But in future new clinics will be added. the administrator must add new table for new clinics and I do not know what to do with these new added tables.

Comment: Look for how to implement multi-tenant databases with EF.